Symfony logout error "Invalid CSRF token."
I have default setting in security.yaml
    logout:
        # The route name the user can go to in order to logout
        path: logout
        # The name of the route to redirect to after logging out
        target: /login

        # Secure the logout against CSRF
        csrf_parameter: token
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

And faced with error "Invalid CSRF token." when user try to logout when it already logged out
Is it ok to remove csrf middleware from logout method ? Is there a better way?

This discussion might be interesting for you: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62769/should-login-and-logout-action-have-csrf-protection

The risk of not having CSRF on a logout POST request, is that an attacker could trick a user to be logged out by visiting an attacker's site. The impact of this is rather low. Why even have a session cookie if a user isn't logged in?
In your case this is not even the case, it sounds like this is just a no-op so there's literally no impact. And if you use SameSite=strict cookies then CSRF tokens are mostly redundant anyway.
